# 'Add role and company' showing on others' profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I just went to [someone's profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389111/bitte-wenden) and saw
a link titled **Add role and company** with the address https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/5389111#career

Clicking the link leads me to "Page not found" error page, so it's not doing anything harmful, but still, it seems like a problem.

See:

[image]

Oh, and it's happening for anyone's profile that I go to. Not just this one.

**Notes:**

- It happens while I'm logged in or logged out
- It's happening on profiles that don't have a careers profile.
- <strike>I have a careers profile</strike> My careers profile is no longer active and it's showing [on mine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/802469/jakar?tab=profile).
- It's happening for profiles [with an 'About Me'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2417948/patrice?tab=profile) and [without](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389111/bitte-wenden)
- **It's not happening on meta profiles**. Just on regular SO profile

Comment: same on my end, but not EVERYONE (you don't have one, for instance)... do you have a careers account? I know I don't.... does this show on MY profile? Because that may be the behavior here : anyone with a careers profile

Comment: @Patrice it doesn't show on your profile.  But it might be related to whether you have an "About Me" or not, not a Careers profile.

Comment: @Patrice Oh wait, you and Jakar have one, I was looking at your meta profile not your main one.

Comment: @davidism just realised that as well.

Comment: Reproducible here. Not having an About Me doesn't seem to affect it http://stackoverflow.com/users/5365654/%E9%BB%84%E5%BB%BA%E5%B3%B0 (Edit: here as in my location, not in meta profiles)

Comment: I updated to answer your comments

Comment: Except on your profile you should be able to click on it without error and add those details.  I just did on my profile. http://stackoverflow.com/users/2571021/dijkgraaf?tab=profile

Comment: Same for me, it's actually a pretty nice new feature. Only that the devs have placed the link *outside* of the user check (or forgot to put in-place a check to check if the browsing user is the account owner or moderator).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry about that. Looks like we missed an "is this my profile?" check there. :)

Fixed pushed, will be live shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: That was... speedy.